# Can the server side hook script of git get the client information such as directory structure or file information of the user pushing to the git?

Tags: git

I am using git as the source code management system at my company.
I want to check the status of the directory or file at the local repository by pre-receive hook of git.

Can the server side hook script of git get the client information such as directory structure or file information of the user pushing to the git?
Any tips?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: This would be a pretty big security problem, if pushing to a server gave the server local filesystem access.

Comment: thank you for the response.

although the hooks script such as pre-commit, post-merge can be used, about some critical problem for the system I want to the server side script.

Comment: for security, exactly right, but the members in my company use git in internal environment.

concretely, I want to check the symbolic link status in local direcotory.

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot. The git protocol only exchanges blob and commit information.

Comment: thank you for the response.
Can I include the local path commited or pushed in in the information exchangeable?

Comment: The only tree information available to a git repo are relative to the root of the repository. You can `mv` your local git copy wherever you want, git won't care. But it will never transmit the _full_ path of any file, since that is not what it is designed to track.